# How to calculate Zero Crossing Rate and Mean Crossing Rate?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, signal-processing

I am trying to calculate ZCR and MCR from accelerometer signal.
My dataset is as follows:

```
#(patient number, time in mill/sec., normalization of X Y and Z, kurtosis, skewness, pitch, roll and yaw, label) respectively.

1,15,-0.248010047716,0.00378335508419,-0.0152548459993,-86.3738760481,0.872322164158,-3.51314800063,0

1,31,-0.248010047716,0.00378335508419,-0.0152548459993,-86.3738760481,0.872322164158,-3.51314800063,0

1,46,-0.267422664673,0.0051143782875,-0.0191247001961,-85.7662354031,1.0928406847,-4.08015176908,0

1,62,-0.267422664673,0.0051143782875,-0.0191247001961,-85.7662354031,1.0928406847,-4.08015176908,0
```

My model is RNN LSTM with python keras

This is what i have tried

```
  a = [1, 2, 1, 1, -3, -4, 7, 8, 9, 10, -2, 1, -3, 5, 6, 7, -10]
    zero_crossings = np.where(np.diff(np.sign(a)))[0]
    print(zero_crossings.shape)
```

The output shape is only 7, and i don't understand why? 
I don't know if that is true and i don't know also how to calculate MCR

Comment: Please share what you've tried already c.f. [ask].

Comment: Done editing !!